# Serverless Lambda with NestJS + Typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, serverless

I try to run serverless offline with NestJS + Typeorm. First time I call to get all users, it worked. But second time, I got an error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

I added `keepConnectionAlive: true` but it doesn't work. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `--allowCache` option.

I'd got exactly same issue with you

This command worked for me.

```
npx sls offline --allowCache start
```